# Kusto declare virtual integer and save its updated state

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I want to declare a variable in Kusto, and after some condition, I want to increase that variable amount by 1.
The problem I am encountering is I can't find a way to update the initial value.

Example:
let n=1;
// how do I update n after each certain condition?

Thanks

Comment: The question is not clear. Please update your question to include sample input (in datatable format), and expected output.

Comment: Does the answer below help? If not, please see my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Kusto does not allow updating the value of variables (whether scalar or not). Are you trying to count the number of rows that satisfy a condition? If so, use the [countif()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/countif-aggfunction) aggregation function

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear. It's best to always have your question include sample input (in datatable format, like I do below), and expected output.

In any case, I'll try to guess that you want to add a column that will be a commulative counter of something. In the example below, I added a column named CounterOfEvenNumbers the value in which increments every time an even Age is encountered.

```
let Data = datatable(Name: string, Age: int) [
    "Paul", 11,
    "Peter", 13,
    "Ann", 16,
    "Steven", 28,
    "Natasha", 31,
    "Don", 35
];
Data
| order by Age asc
| extend CounterOfEvenNumbers = row_cumsum(iff(Age % 2 == 0, 1, 0))
```

Output:

| Name | Age | CounterOfEvenNumbers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Paul | 11 | 0 |
| Peter | 13 | 0 |
| Ann | 16 | 1 |
| Steven | 28 | 2 |
| Natasha | 31 | 2 |
| Don | 35 | 2 |